# How to update null cells of specific column with average of numerical values in that column ? (Mysql using java)

Tags: java, mysql

I want to take average of all numerical values in a column & update the null cells in that column with calculated average But facing problem during update of null cells.... please give me suggestions... Following is my code...

```
/*---------------- Function to apply Mean Imputation Algorithm on saved data in Database -----------------*/
public void CalcMean(String tableName) {

        Statement stmt = null;
        String sql = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {

            setConnection();
            //connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
            System.out.println("sql :" + sql);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            CachedRowSet rowset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
            rowset.populate(rs);

            while(rowset.next()){

                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rowset.getMetaData();
                int numOfCols = rsmd.getColumnCount();//get total number of columns from database

                    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfCols; i++){
                        if (rowset.getString(i)== null || rowset.getString(i).equals("*") || rowset.getString(i).equals("?"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("was NULL"+i);// Database contains NULL
                            String nullCellValue = rowset.getString(i);// get the designated cell's value
                            System.out.println(nullCellValue);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("not NULL"+i);// Database does not contain NULL
                            String cellValue = rowset.getString(i);// get the designated cell's value

                            System.out.println(cellValue);

                            /*----- check if the value in cell is Numerical or Categorical [0-9]+-----*/
                            String regex = "[0-9.]+";

                                if(cellValue.matches(regex)){
                                    System.out.println("Value is numerical");

                                    String colName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                                    System.out.println(colName);

                                    CalcNumericValMean(colName , tableName);

                            }
                            else{
                                System.out.println("Value is categorical");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

            //Clean-up environment
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            //connection.commit();
            closeConnection();

        }/*catch (SQLException ex) {
            try {
                connection.rollback();
                System.out.println("RollBack performed");
                closeConnection();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println("RollBack failed");
                }
            } */
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
// Function to Calculate Mean of Numeric Values 
public void CalcNumericValMean(String colName , String tableName){

    Statement st = null;
    String sql = null;
    String average = null;

    try{

        setConnection();
        //connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        st = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            sql = "SELECT AVG( " + colName + " ) FROM " + tableName;
            System.out.println("sql :" + sql);

            ResultSet rset = st.executeQuery(sql);
            CachedRowSet rowset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
            rowset.populate(rset);

            int i = 1;
            while(rowset.next()) {  // check if a result was returned
                  average = rowset.getString(i); // get your result
                  System.out.println("average is : " + average);
                  i++;
                }

        //Clean-up environment
        rset.close();
        st.close(); 
        //connection.commit();
        closeConnection();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What issue do you have?

Comment: In update of null values with average of numerical values in column.... give some suggestion how to do that......?

Comment: I didn't find any UPDATE statement in your code. Did you try: `"UPDATE " + tableName + " SET colName = " + avarage + " WHERE " + colName + " IS NULL"`?

Comment: Yes sir, I want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try your implementation with table model? . Table model overrides contain public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) which you can ovveride and do the math on a specific column of your table

Comment: Can you please explain it more... How to do that? . I am not familiar with Table Model.

Comment: you can get more info by reading the Jtable tutorial. It is quite straight forward and covers most of the topics you will need for JTables https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html